# Can the word 'slab' be used to mean 'range'? For example, distance slab and weight slab (in technical specifications), income tax slab

Tags: meaning, scientific-language

In Merriam-Webster dictionary, none of the meaning of 'slab' is 'range'. But slab is also used to mean range in India. For example, limit X1 for weight slab 10-20kg, limit X2 for slab 20-30 kg.

Comment: I've never heard *slab* used to convey *range*. Also, I would interpret "limit X1 for weight slab 10-20 kg* as meaning X1 is the limit for slabs weighing 10-20 kg." Do you have another example not involving weight?

Comment: Freight charges X1 for transporting a box in a weight slab 100-200kg, X2 for transporting a box in a weight slab 200-300kg.   Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native English speaker and not heard it used like this as far as I can remember but if I did hear someone use it like this I wouldn't find fault with it. I did some research on this and found it used in text describing "price slabs" which means "pricing ranges" e.g., $0-500:
[https://support.reportgarden.com/en/articles/2002057-about-slab-based-pricing#:~:text=Slabs%20are%20adspend%20(usage)%20ranges,the%20slab%20for%20each%20range](https://support.reportgarden.com/en/articles/2002057-about-slab-based-pricing#:%7E:text=Slabs%20are%20adspend%20(usage)%20ranges,the%20slab%20for%20each%20range).

I think "slab" is just a generic describer of a "large-piece" of anything. It sounds a bit slangy maybe? But I think should be fine to use it in any context.

Comment: Thank you, @user2980368

Answer (score 1):

I've seen "slab" used this way occasionally, kind of in the same metaphoric sense that "slice" might be used.  It's not particularly idiomatic, though.